# Positional Argument when adding a search bar on google map in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Google Maps'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              TextFormField(),
              IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.search))
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
      GoogleMap(
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          markers: _markers,
          initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: _kGooglePlex, zoom: 14),
          onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        )
    );
  }
```

I was following a tutorial video however when I add a column to add a search bar to try google places API, the Google Map part of the code triggered a too many positional argument, I am still new in flutter so I have no idea how to fix this.

Adding a search bar on the google map so I could try the google places API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place widget inside `childred`.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Google Maps'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              TextFormField(),
              IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.search))
            ],
          ),
          GoogleMap( //inside column
            mapType: MapType.normal,
            markers: _markers,
            initialCameraPosition:
                CameraPosition(target: _kGooglePlex, zoom: 14),
            onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Find more about [`Column`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flutter Typeahead field](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead) for Google Place search field..
I hope it's help you :}